# How do Display A Layout With a Variable Number of Items in an Array (PHP)

Tags: php, html, arrays, zurb-foundation

If I give you an `array` of objects, lets assume there are x number of objects how would you do the following using a grid system (bootstrap, foundation ... doesn't matter):

Loop Over the array and create something that replicates:

[image]

No I have been able to create this by doing:

```
echo "<div class='row'>";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($options['fields']); $i++) {

        // Increate the value of I and convert it from 1 to one.
        $numberToWord = new FreyaTheme\NumberToWord\Conversion();
        $wordRepersentation = $numberToWord->convert($i + 1);

        if (isset($options['fields']['logo_image_' . $wordRepersentation])) {
            if ($i <= 2) {
                echo '<div class="medium-4 columns r3x1">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$options['fields']['logo_image_' . $wordRepersentation].'" />';
                echo '</div>';
            } else if ($i <= 6) {
                echo '<div class="medium-3 columns r4x1">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$options['fields']['logo_image_' . $wordRepersentation].'" />';
                echo '</div>';
            } else if ($i <= 9) {
                echo '<div class="medium-4 columns r3x1">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$options['fields']['logo_image_' . $wordRepersentation].'" />';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
echo "</div>";
```

Now this, while a bit messy with the logic here - works for 10 items. Now imagine I give you 800. or 8 or 2 or 1 or ... you get the idea. Regardless of how many items I give you, this pattern, this box layout needs to repeat. I don't care if you give me 6 or 6000 objects.

**I can do this with 10, but I don't know how to scale it. Ideas?**

Comment: `if($i%2 == 0){'put code for three images'}else{'put code for three images'}`

Comment: it means check even and odd row and then do code accordingly.

Comment: @AK-Sonu I think one of those should be (`else`) `'put code for four images'`

Comment: @AK-Sonu Can you put this as an answer to the question, if in fact it is - while also expanding on what you mean?

Comment: @KyleAdams i think you want images based on row type.That means if row number is odd like first third and so on then three images will show. If rows are even like second, fourth and so on then four images will show. Am i right?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek YOU ARE  correct. a bit mistake done. but i think it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is one solution. Ofc you have to make it responsive yourself and use css classes instead of inline css:

```
<div style="padding: 5px; text-align:center;">
    <?php
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i)
    {
    ?>
    <div>
    <?php
        //output 3
        if ($i%2 == 0)
        {
            for($cell=0;$cell<3;++$cell)
            {
            ?>
            <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid #000; width: 200px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <span style="padding: 40px; display:inline-block; text-align:center;">350*150</span>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
        }
        //output 4
        else
        {
            for($cell=0;$cell<4;++$cell)
            {
            ?>
            <div style="padding: 5px; display:inline-block; border:1px solid red; width: 138px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <span style="padding: 30px; display:inline-block; text-align:center;">350*150</span>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```