# Create a layout based on Object count which is variable (PHP)

Tags: php, html, zurb-foundation

so I recently asked a question [which for all intense and purposes was correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632266/how-do-display-a-layout-with-a-variable-number-of-items-in-an-array-php/31632448#31632448).

How ever the issue is that the out put is not what I want.

In the answer I stated I needed to replicate this type of layout, which I demonstrated how I got with exactly 10 objects.

[image]

The problem with the following code:

```
echo "<div class='row'>";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($options['fields']); $i++) {

        // Increate the value of I and convert it from 1 to one.
        $numberToWord = new FreyaTheme\NumberToWord\Conversion();
        $wordRepersentation = $numberToWord->convert($i + 1);

        if (isset($options['fields']['logo_image_' . $wordRepersentation])) {
            if ($i <= 2) {
                echo '<div class="medium-4 columns r3x1">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$options['fields']['logo_image_' . $wordRepersentation].'" />';
                echo '</div>';
            } else if ($i <= 6) {
                echo '<div class="medium-3 columns r4x1">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$options['fields']['logo_image_' . $wordRepersentation].'" />';
                echo '</div>';
            } else if ($i <= 9) {
                echo '<div class="medium-4 columns r3x1">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$options['fields']['logo_image_' . $wordRepersentation].'" />';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
echo "</div>";
```

Is that it works, for only ten objects.

The answer I was given gives me this layout, 10 times. Thats not what I want.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($logoPosts); $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 === 0) {
        for ($cell = 0; $cell < 4; $cell++) {
            echo '<div class="medium-3 columns">Hello World 3</div>';
        }
    } else {
        for ($cell = 0; $cell < 3; $cell++) {
            echo '<div class="medium-4 columns">Hello World 4</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the above picture layout 10 times. There are only 10 objects. So this should only out put once. If there were twenty this layout should happen twice. and so on and so forth.

The catch is that if the person only gives x the layout should retain its shape.

**There is one issue with this layout**:

Lets say I give you 22 objects. this is where the classes need to change. so far, for 3 objects you get `medium-4` and for 4 objects you get `medium-3`.

But because I gave you 22 objects it should go a little something like this:

```
medium-4 | medium-4 | medium-4 |
medium-3 | medium-3 | medium-3 | medium-3
medium-4 | medium-4 | medium-4 |
medium-4 | medium-4 | medium-4 |
medium-3 | medium-3 | medium-3 | medium-3
medium-4 | medium-4 | medium-4 |
medium-6 | medium-6
```

As you can see, I have done 10, 10, 2 for a total of 22 objects.

Imagine I give you 67 objects: 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 4, 3

So the point is the columns have to change based on the `count($logoPosts)`.

**How would I achieve this?**

Lets Start with 12. What I would get is the following:

```
medium-4 | medium-4 | medium-4 |
medium-3 | medium-3 | medium-3 | medium-3
medium-4 | medium-4 | medium-4 |
medium-6 | medium-6
```